# "File not found at..." error when loading KML into Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, kml

I have a KML file on a public URL like http://host.com/dir/file.kml

If I put that KML file on another server, and put the new URL in the search box on Google Maps, it loads the KML into google maps.

If I put the above URL into google maps like so: http://maps.google.com/maps?q=http://host.com/dir/file.kml

It does not load, and I get the following message:

```
File not found at http://host.com/dir/f....

Suggestions:

    Make sure the URL is spelled correctly.
    Make sure the file exists.
```

Therefore, I assume this is a configuration issue on the server. They are not being very helpful with debugging/configuring. Can anyone here offer advice on how to fix this?

Comment: Hi I'm in same problem now, refer to http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/mapsSupport.html , on size and restriction KML, they said that kml's should not bigger than 10MB and maximum fetched size of raw kml is 3MB :( My file is bigger than allowable size, I think it have to splitted :D

Comment: Try KMZ which is smaller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to http://groups.google.com/group/Google-Maps-API/browse_thread/thread/3a9ece02830693ea/df4db2d551c2753f, you have to add this to htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_security.c> 
  SecFilterEngine Off 
  SecFilterScanPOST Off 
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I don't know if that is the solution or not. I tried it myself in a local .htaccess and it did not have an effect. The host has now done something (unknown to me) and it now works...

Answer (score 5):

Important note on using KML & KMZ on your hosted server

Windows:

Set the MIME on the server for accessing kml/kmz for Google Earth, Google Maps & Google Maps API  reads KML and KMZ files.
The standard MIME type for KML files is

```
* application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml
```

The standard MIME type for KMZ files is

```
* application/vnd.google-earth.kmz
```

For Apache, add these lines to the httpd.conf file or a .htaccess file in the same folder (if your host only allows htaccess rather than httpd.conf access):

```
* AddType application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml .kml
* AddType application/vnd.google-earth.kmz .kmz
```

For Linux:

```
* AddType application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml .kml  

* AddType application/vnd.google-earth.kmz .kmz  

  Application: opt/google-earth/googleearth
```

I posted this here back in 2007
 http://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-api/web/more-info-kml-on-google-maps

Answer (score 0):

Other issue you can have is if your KML file is too large for google maps. Tells you file can't be found, but it takes a bit longer than a straight URL error.

Also, if you are on something that doesn't want to serve .kml or .kmz properly, you can use .xml or .zip and it seems to work.